# Can't run a SQL job on remote server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to run a job on a remote server at the end of my stored procedure.

I'm using this code

```
exec msdb..sp_start_job @job_name = 'MyJob', @server_name = 'divss403'
```

However it keeps saying that the job doesn't exist

```
Msg 14262, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_job_identifiers, Line 67
The specified @job_name ('MyJob') does not exist.
```

The job definitely exists and is spelt correctly

My AD account has access to execute that job on the remote server and if I run this code on that server the job starts.

I'm guessing it's a rights issue but I'm not sure where I should be looking

Comment: "if I run this code on that server the job starts." Can you explain exactly the two ways you are running this code?

Comment: Running it from Server 1 and it fails to execute the job on Server 2. Running it on Server 2 gets the job to run on Server 2

Comment: Running from server 1 - do you mean you log into Server 1 locally, start SSMS on that server then connect to Server 2 through SSMS then run that code? Please be specific.

Comment: Server1.StoredProc <- running it from there and I need a job on Server2 to run. If I run the query on Server2 in the msdb database it starts the job on server 2.. however I need to run it from Server 1

Comment: "run the query on Server2" do you mean you open SSMS and connect to server 2 and run that code? What happens when you follow SQLDBA's advice?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It turns out that the LINKed server did not get created properly or something. Removing the LINK server and adding it again solved the issue. Also try linking server first > hit OK, and then go to properties of this link to enable RPC and RPC out.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the server name so you are using a FQDN, like this:

```
exec remoteserverhere.msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'MyJob', @server_name = 'divss403'
```

Just connect to the remote server in SSMS first.

Comment: Do I have to have the servers connected via SSMS?

Comment: Add a Linked Server (Server2 on Server1).  The way it is now, the EXEC thinks you want to run it on the local server.  The FQDN tells MSSQL that it is remote.

Comment: Good point.  server_name refers to one of the "targeted servers."  When you set up the job, you can specify targeted server(s).  The default is local. If server_name is not one of the targeted servers then it will not work.